# No internet connection linux mint even after getting connected to the wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet

I'm having problem with my internet connection it was all fine but suddenly I'm not getting or receiving data even after connection,I checked my wlan0 it's up ,it getting the ssid and of course I can see signal is full strength ,but still I'm unable to connect

This is my `ifconfig` output:

```
 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:8e:04:bf:6a  
 inet addr:172.21.85.52  Bcast:172.21.85.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
 inet6 addr: fe80::a3e:8eff:fe04:bf6a/64 Scope:Link
 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
 RX packets:6085 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
 TX packets:799 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
 RX bytes:782378 (782.3 KB)  TX bytes:103292 (103.2 KB)
```

This is my `route -n` output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.21.84.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
172.21.84.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

Comment: what is the output of "ifconfig" and "route -n" ?

Comment: What is your network card model? Are you not able to connect to the network or is it that you can't browse the internet?

Comment: i can connect but not able to browse..

Comment: @aseaudiI will post the output tomorrow as I'm not in the network I'm facing problem...

Comment: Are you able to ping the router ?

Comment: no I can only ping when I'm using lan not when I'm connected to wifi